# Does Amazon aws lex chatbot supports videos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am new to Amazon aws, Is lex chat bot support video eg MP4 , ?

Assume something like this:

Bot: would you like to watch the tutorial?

Human: Yes.

Bot: displays a video

A video can be alone or with response card .
Is this possible????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom payload as a response from a Lex bot (using a Lambda function for the fulfillment), but you would also have to integrate the Lex bot into an application that could appropriately handle that response (display the video based on the response from the Lex fulfillment lambda).

The supported message formats are:

- PlainText—The message contains plain UTF-8 text.
- SSML—The message contains text formatted for voice output.
- **CustomPayload—The message contains a custom format that you have created for your client. You can define the payload to meet the needs of your application.**
- Composite—The message is a collection of messages, one from each message group. For more information about message groups, see Message Groups.

Moere info on Lex messaging and the CustomPayload here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-manage-prompts.html

So the answer is that it is possible, but not a built in functionality.

Comment: examples will be depending on which chat client you are using @user9964622

Comment: hi dylan I tried to do as u said but i have little problem here is thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167277/custom-payload-on-amazon-lex-aws-with-lambda?noredirect=1#comment98963572_56167277

Answer (score 2):

Amazon lex will be able to send whatever response is required, it's the job of chat client to render that response and displays accordingly.
There will be a different way to send a video in response to facebook messenger than slack or any other chat client.

If you need to deploy it to your website, you can check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/) and [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui#examples) out. It supports HTML and markdown components in response so you can send a video.